# QGIS zoom to predefined scale with mouse wheel

Tags: qgis-3, scale, zoom

Do you know if it is possible to set QGIS to zoom to the predefined scales (in project options) when using the mouse wheel ?

Answer (score 3):

An answer using PyQGIS, mainly adapted from [Set predefined scales in PyQGIS for standalone application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167143/set-predefined-scales-in-pyqgis-for-standalone-application). I'm not aware of a GUI approach to do so (?!)

It influences both classic zoom and mouse wheel behaviour

```py
# Get the predefined scales from your project
myscales = QgsProject.instance().viewSettings().mapScales()

def forcedScale(scales=None):
    if scales is None:
        predefinedScales = [
            591657528,
            295828764,
            147914382,
            73957191,
            36978595,
            18489298,
            9244649,
            4622324,
            2311162,
            1155581,
            577791,
            288895,
            144448,
            72224,
            36112,
            18056,
            9028,
            4514,
            2257,
            1128,
            564,
            282,
            141,
            71
        ]
    def zoomToScale(scale):
        mapcanvas.scaleChanged.disconnect(zoomToScale)
        targetScale = min(scales, key=lambda x:abs(x-scale))
        mapcanvas.zoomScale(targetScale )
        mapcanvas.scaleChanged.connect(zoomToScale)
    mapcanvas.scaleChanged.connect(zoomToScale)

# Execute once
forcedScale(myscales)
```

Comment: Thank you. However I don't know how to implement this code in my QGIS project so I can apply it. Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't involve the mouse wheel, but you could create a [Spatial Bookmark](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=bookmark#spatial-bookmarks), possibly?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pfalbaum, however I don't need Spatial bookmarks. What I want is that scrolling with the mouse wheel stops at predefined scales.